# Selecting a record where data in anouther column is at min

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, min

I need to get the record of two numbers in two columns. But I need to find where the min value is of one of the columns. And find the number that is aligned to that min number.

Right now I have the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, MIN(price) AS minPrice FROM my_table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row["minPrice"]; // This works
echo $row["ID"]; // This is not the number that is in the record where minPrice is.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for one row, the simplest method is `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.col2 asc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use subqueries.

```
Select ID from my_table t, (select min(price) as minPrice from my_table) where t.price =minPrice;
```

Didn't tested it, but it should work.

It returns all the ids with the minimal price.